# What is this piece and what is its number?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

Does anyone know what number piece this is?
[image: Cropped image of LEGO element]

Answer (score 10):

Looks like it's Support 2 x 4 x 5 Stanchion Inclined [4476a](http://rebrickable.com/parts/4476a) or [4476b](http://rebrickable.com/parts/4476b).